# How to organize photos within data in a text field?

Tags: livecode

Currently I am able to load all of the photos onto the page, however, they all load in the center of the app on top of one another. I want to have the images display before the data it belongs with.

For example:

[photo]

Name:

Sex:

Age:

[photo]

Name:

Sex:

Age:

...

This is my code currently (data loaded from xml url) and I have tried to look at `rect` and other properties, but I have not been able to have any luck.

```
 repeat for each line tChild in tChildren
  add 1 to x
  put revXMLChildNames( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&backslash, return, "adoptableSearch", true) into tAdoptable

  put revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Photo") into tURL
  put url tUrl into tPhoto
  if the result is empty then
     set the text of img x to tPhoto
  else
     beep
  end if

  put "Name: " & revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Name") & return after tData
  ...
 end repeat
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As you have no creation of the images in your code I assume that you have created them before the repeat loop, then you will need to lock the size and position of the image.

My other suggestion is to create a template group with an image and one or more fields (name, sex, age etc). You can then create a nice layout for each part. When done you can lock everything within the group but still easily set the location for the complete group. Finally you can then move the template group outside the card or hide it.

```
put 50 into tTop
put 20 into tLeft
put the width of group "templateGroup" into tTempGW
put the height of group "templateGroup" into tTempGH
put 0 into tCount
repeat for each line tChild in tChildren
   copy group "templateGroup" to this card
   put it into tGroupID         # It holds the long id after a copy operation
   put url tUrl into tPhoto
   if the result is empty then
     set the text of img 1 of tGroupID to tPhoto
  else
     beep
  end if
  # Position the new group
  set the topLeft of tGroupID to tLeft,tTop
  add tTempGW to tLeft
  if tLeft + tTempGW > the width of this stack then
     # Next item will be partly outside so we move down 
     add tTempGH to tTop
     put 20 into tLeft
  end if
  # Set some proper name
  add 1 to tCount
  set the name of tGroupID to ("Person" && tCount)
  put revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Name") into field "name" of tGroupID
  ...
end repeat
```

You can of course use other values for top and left. I usually use an empty group to hold all other groups then you use the boundaries for that group as top, left, right.